# Were Adam and Eve ever given the permission by God to procreate?

Tags: genesis, adam-and-eve

If it was wrong to know that you were naked. How could it be right to procreate. Procreation is caused massive chaos in the world. It is also responsible for overpopulation of the universe. And also for evil doings such as the printing of money. Which is used to make people believe that it is the true meaning of life. While people have to long after money so that they can pay their bills have a roof over their head and survive in the world. Procreation is the reason why we have war and the reason why we have most things that have caused death in the world as we know it.  God meant for two people to exist. With the benefits of knowing him. And reaping the benefits of what he created for them.

Comment: Why would such a complex organ system never be used? It would be like giving humans gills to breath underwater, but then commanding that humans never go underwater. Clearly God meant for humans to procreate.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange. This is a site that discusses the beliefs of many different Christian denominations and traditions.  You need to specify the Christian tradition or denomination from which you seek answers and avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based. Good questions show research and provide evidence of any claims made.  When you have a moment, please take the Christianity Stack tour to learn more about us:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 10):

It says in Genesis:

> 26 Then God said, “Let us make mankind in our image, in our likeness,
>   so that they may rule over the fish in the sea and the birds in the
>   sky, over the livestock and all the wild animals,[a] and over all the
>   creatures that move along the ground.”
>
> 27 So God created mankind in his own image,
>       in the image of God he created them;
>       male and female he created them.
>
> 28 God blessed them and said to them, “Be fruitful and increase in
>   number; fill the earth and subdue it. Rule over the fish in the sea
>   and the birds in the sky and over every living creature that moves on
>   the ground.”

God commanded Adam and Eve (not just the animals) to be fruitful and multiply.

The awareness of nakedness only came about after Adam and Eve sinned. One purpose of clothing is to restrain lust which leads to the destruction of families. When Adam and Eve were innocent, they would not have experienced lust, so there would not be any need for clothing, except to protect against cold, which might not have been a problem in Eden.

All the negative effects that you attach to procreation are really the effects of sin. We have no clue how the world would look if Adam and Eve had not sinned. I presume that the same Creator who commanded "fill the world" would issue another command when it was filled to slow down or stop having offspring, and an obedient creation would have listened.

Comment: You raised an interesting point in your last paragraph. How do we know when the command to fill the earth with people is achieved?

Comment: I do not want you to be ignorant of this mystery, brothers and sisters, so that you may not be conceited: Israel has experienced a hardening in part until the full number of the Gentiles has come in, (Romans 11:25, NIV) It seems there is a specific number of believers that God is waiting for before history reaches its completion.

Answer (score 0):

*Were Adam and Eve ever given the permission by God to procreate?*

**The answer is YES and NO!**

**EXPLANATION**

1. The Catechism of the Church teaches that Adam & Eve were destined to be divinized". In the Eastern Churches it is called "Theosis".

> 398 In that sin man preferred himself to God and by that very act scorned him. He chose himself over and against God, against the requirements of his creaturely status and therefore against his own good. ***Constituted in a state of holiness, man was destined to be fully "divinized" by God in glory. Seduced by the devil, he wanted to "be like God", but "without God, before God, and not in accordance with God"***.279 (St. Maximus the Confessor, Ambigua: PG 91,1156C; cf. Gen 3:5.
>
> **Theosis, or deification (deification may also refer to apotheosis, lit. "making divine")**, is a transformative process whose aim is likeness to or union with God, as taught by the Eastern Orthodox Church and Eastern Catholic Churches. As a process of transformation, theosis is brought about by the effects of catharsis (purification of mind and body) and theoria ('illumination' with the 'vision' of God). According to Eastern Christian teaching, theosis is very much the purpose of human life. It is considered achievable only through a synergy (or cooperation) between human activity and God's uncreated energies (or operations).[1]
>   **Theosis (Eastern Christian theology)**https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theosis_(Eastern_Christian_theology)

Can Adam & Eve reach "theosis" if they committed the "sexual procreation" that will involve uncontrollable "sexual passions"? No!, Adam & Eve must offer their bodies to glorify God.

> **A Living Sacrifice** 12 *Therefore, I urge you, brothers and sisters, in view of God’s mercy, to offer your bodies as a living sacrifice, holy and pleasing to God—this is your true and proper worship.* (Romans12:1)

2. What is the relationship of Adam & Eve in paradise before the fall? Are they "husband and wife" already or just a "helpmate" for each other?

The Book of Genesis narration that Adam only gave the name Eve to the deceived Woman after their fall, so Adam did not possessed the Woman before the fall. Their relationship is not "conjugal".

> 369 Man and woman have been created, which is to say, willed by God: on the one hand, in perfect equality as human persons; on the other, in their respective beings as man and woman. "Being man" or "being woman" is a reality which is good and willed by God: man and woman possess an inalienable dignity which comes to them immediately from God their Creator.240 Man and woman are both with one and the same dignity "in the image of God". In their "being-man" and "being-woman", they reflect the Creator's wisdom and goodness.

If their relationship is not "conjugal", is sexual procreation be permitted by God?

3. What is the role of Adam in the garden? Did God made him to become a Father of children?

> 358 God created everything for man,222 but man in turn was created to serve and love God and to offer all creation back to him:

Adam were made to ***"offer all creation back to Him"***. If God made Adam to offer, then what is his role? Is Adam a Priest because only a priest can offer to God.

The answer is Yes, because Adam is not just an ordinary Priest but a High Priest and God place Adam in the garden of Eden situated in the east meaning that place is a "place of worship" where Adam can offer to God "the creation back to Him" to glorify His Holy Name.

Any references to support the teachings that Adam is a High Priest and that the Garden of Eden is the Temple of God or the Sanctuary of God.

The references below are the works of Biblical Scholars and Catholic Catechist. Please read the links;

1.**Adam: High priest of humanity**
https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/resources/sacraments/holy-orders/adam-high-priest-of-humanity

2. **THE GARDEN OF EDEN AS GOD'S FIRST SANCTUARY** (*LIFSA SCHACHTER )*
   https://jbqnew.jewishbible.org/assets/Uploads/412/jbq_41_2_gardenofeden.pdf
3. Adam & Eve were Clothe with a Garments of Light, and we can that Adam & Eve after their fall had realized that they were naked. Did they committed "sexual procreation" because they see themselves "naked"?

> **Revelations to Blessed Anne Catherine Emmerich of Westphalia, Germany (1774 – 1824),** from her four-volume Life of Jesus Christ and Biblical Revelations. (TAN Books, or online here).  The following is from Chapter Three of the first volume.
>
> *They were like two unspeakably noble and beautiful children, perfectly luminous. and clothed with beams of light as with a veil. From Adam's mouth I saw issuing a broad stream of glittering light, and upon his forehead was an expression of great majesty. Around his mouth played a sunbeam, but there was none around Eve's. I saw Adam's heart very much the same as in men of the present day, but his breast was surrounded by rays of light. In the middle of his heart, I saw a sparkling halo of glory.* 
>   http://divinefiat.blogspot.com/2014/02/were-adam-and-eve-originally-clothed-in.html

In closing, the word of God saying ***"be fruitful and multiply"*** must be put in the proper context if we want it to relate to "procreation". Adam & Eve was created to fulfill God commandment to Adam & Eve to "offer back God's creation back to Him" to glorify His Holy Name.

Before the fall happened, Adam & Eve are offering "God's creation and the works of their hands and they are using their sinless body" to glorify God.

After the fall, the words "be fruitful and multiply" will take a new meaning, as clearly their relationship from "helpmate" to "conjugal" is now seen.

So to answer your question, *"Were Adam and Eve ever given the permission by God to procreate?"*

**The answer is Yes**, only after the fall but before the fall Adam & Eve was not given permission to procreate, as they were destined to be "divinized or reach Theosis".

Answer (score 0):

the general population is not familiar with the sacred practice of procreations, ascending into Chrism, and procreating a sacred Christ into the third dimension. The essenes knew of these practices and so did the priest of annuknaki Adam and eves time period, of which Adam and his group were to be consulted prior to the act of pro creating, in order to manifest higher beings, When Adam explained what was told by the annuaknaki, to Seth, he said for every generations of those who did not follow the precise teachings, that those generations would fall further away from their inherent rights to ascension or resurrect and to clearly face God as their normal awareness

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).